# How to find the errors in the core file?

Tags: c

I have run a C program which creates segmentation fault and creates core file.
I need clear explanation in which place the segmentation fault occurs in core file.
How to read that core file.

```
#include "stdio.h"
main()
 {
  char *ptr;
  *ptr=100;
  printf("\nPointer Value is :%s\n", ptr) ;
}
```

You have to run this program and change the ulimit of the core file size as unlimited 
Use this command :

```
$ulimit -c unlimited
```

Then compile this C program and run the program segmentation fault will occur and core file
will be created. How to read the core file and find where the segmentation fault is occurring.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a pointer, which is uninitialized (i.e. you don't make it point to anything). As all uninitialized local variables, the value of it is indeterminate and probably random, so you don't know where it points.

You then attempt to write a number to this random location, and that leads to undefined behavior. Undefined behavior is not predictable, and it *may* work, it *may* cause something unexpected to happen, it *may* crash the program, or it *may* even cause [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

You *further* try to use that pointer as a string, which once a gain leads to two instance of undefined behavior: Once because the pointer is uninitialized, and once more when `printf` reads byte after byte to find the string terminator.

---

There is also another case of undefined behavior, and that is that your `main` function is not correctly defined. It should return an `int` and either take a `void` argument or a `int` and a `char**` argument. This is in the C specification. Not having a proper `main` is technically an illegal program, but unfortunately it's so common that compilers let it slip.

---

To use it in a debugger, you either run the program in the debugger:

```
$ gdb ./myProgram
...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/someone/myProgram

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400518 in main () at myProgram.c:5
5     *ptr=100;
(gdb)
```

Or after it crashes and creates a core dump, you run the debugger using the core dump:

```
$ ./myProgram
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ gdb ./myProgram core
...
Reading symbols from /home/someone/myProgram...done.
[New LWP 4655]

Core was generated by `./myProgram'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000400518 in main () at myProgram.c:5
5     *ptr=100;
(gdb)
```

By the way, for the debugging information (the "symbols" the debugger reads) the program have to be compiled with the `-g` flag.

Comment: The question wording is a little ambiguous, but I think the question is more about "how do I read the core dump file to determine the problem", in case the program is less trivial than this example.

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn how to use the debugger. I am guessing you are using Linux.

So first, compile your program with

```
 gcc -g -Wall prog.c -o progbin
```

You'll get a warning about `ptr` not being initialized; please fix that. You probably need something like

```
 char somebuf[10];
 ptr = somebuf;
```

or like

```
 ptr = malloc(10);
 if (!ptr) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

Then use the debugger live

```
 gdb progbin
```

at the `(gdb)` prompt, type `help`. Then read the [GDB documentation](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/): very useful GDB commands are `bt` (backtrace), `r` (run), `b` (break), `c` (continue), `p` (print), `n` (next), `s` (step), `watch` ...

To debug (that is "read a core file") a core dump which you *already* have:

```
 gdb progbin core
```

and use some gdb commands, notably `bt` (backtrace, to get the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack)) and `p` (to print some variables or expressions, and `up` & `down` to walk thru the callstack); be sure that `progbin` was built with the `-g` option to the compiler.

Given a `core` file you might get the file of the program which has crashed with `file core`  command.

Answer (score 2):

Compiling the program with little or no optimization with debugging
annotations that will be used by the debugger makes things a lot
easier:

```
$ gcc -g -ggdb -O0 foo.c -o foo
```

After loading the core file into gdb...

```
$ gdb progbin core
```

... the location where the crash happened is printed:

```
Core was generated by `./foo'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x0000000000400509 in main () at foo.c:5
5         *ptr=100;
```

In more complex programs, it makes sense to print a backtrace. (In
this trivial program it will get you no more useful information:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400509 in main () at foo.c:5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read your coredump file by passing it to gdb.
According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) core dump file consists of the recorded state of the working memory of a computer program at a specific time, generally when the program has terminated abnormally (crashed).

Generally gdb accepts executable for debugging purpose. If you pass an executable to gdb it executes that program and provides related information.

If you pass coredump file along with your executable to gdb, it examines your program as it is crashed before.

Comment: Good, but `gdb` won't execute a program from a `core` dump, just examine it!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, Thats what i mean to say... you can edit my post to make it good.